# How to repeat the last 5 rows of a table on the next page?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I've been searching for an answer for this but cant find a good tutorial. I'm using Java itext to generate a pdf. I have a table which prints over 50 rows which eats around 2 pages. I need to print the last 5 rows of the previous page to the next page before continuing printing the list.

`Example:
row 31
row 32
row 33
row 34
row 35
row 36
--end of page 1--
row 32
row 33
row 34
row 35
row 36
row 37`

Any idea on how to do this?

`Currently it prints like this:
row 35
row 36
--end of page 1--
row 37
row 38`

Code: (Focus on start loop and never mind those headers)

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);
table.setWidthPercentage(97);
table.setWidths(new float[] {10, 45, 25, 25});

PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Logo", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 14)));
c1.setPadding(5);
c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
c1.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
c1.setBorder(0);
c1.setColspan(4);
table.addCell(c1);

c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("09/01/2013 - 09/15/2013", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 12)));
c1.setPadding(5);
c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
c1.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
c1.setBorder(0);
c1.setColspan(4);
c1.setPaddingBottom(20);
table.addCell(c1);

//start header
c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" ", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 12)));
c1.setPaddingBottom(5);
c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
c1.setBackgroundColor(WebColors.getRGBColor("#99CCFF"));
c1.setBorder(1);
table.addCell(c1);

c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Name", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 12)));
c1.setPaddingBottom(5);
c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
c1.setBackgroundColor(WebColors.getRGBColor("#99CCFF"));
c1.setBorder(1);
table.addCell(c1);

c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Number", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 12)));
c1.setPaddingBottom(5);
c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
c1.setBackgroundColor(WebColors.getRGBColor("#99CCFF"));
c1.setBorder(1);
table.addCell(c1);

c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Amount", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 12)));
c1.setPaddingBottom(5);
c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
c1.setBackgroundColor(WebColors.getRGBColor("#99CCFF"));
c1.setBorder(1);
table.addCell(c1);
//end header

//start for loop
for(int a=0; a<50; a++)
{
    int border=0;
    if(a%5==0)
    {border=1;}

    c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase((a+1)+"", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 12)));
    c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
    c1.setBorder(border);
    c1.setPaddingBottom(5);
    table.addCell(c1);

    c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Last Name, First Name", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 12)));
    c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
    c1.setBorder(border);
    c1.setPaddingBottom(5);
    table.addCell(c1);

    c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("1", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 12)));
    c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    c1.setBorder(border);
    c1.setPaddingBottom(5);
    table.addCell(c1);

    c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("1", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 12)));
    c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    c1.setBorder(border);
    c1.setPaddingBottom(5);
    table.addCell(c1);


}
//end for loop

subCatPart.add(table);
```

Comment: @Sandeep: already found that and it doesn't answer my question

Comment: Is the size of the table always the same or does it depend on a parameter each time you run your program?

Comment: @MichaëlDemey its a variable. i just fixed it to 50 on that code to simulate multiple pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't achieve this by using `document.add()`; instead you need to write specific rows using the `writeSelectedRows()` method. See for instance the [RepeatLastRows](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/RepeatLastRows) method.

In this example, I have a table with 99 rows. If I would use `document.add()` to add this table to a document, it would take 3 pages, and the third page would only show 3 rows. You want this page to show 5 rows, repeating 2 rows from the previous page.

This is how it's done, assuming that we have an A4 page with a margin of 36pt. This means that the available surface measures 523 by 770 pt:

```
// we create a table that spans the width of the page and that has 99 rows
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
table.setTotalWidth(523);
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
    table.addCell("row " + i);
```

Note that I set the total width. You'll get an exception if you use `writeSelectedRows()` without specifying a width.

We initialize some parameters:

```
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
int currentRowStart = 0;
int currentRow = 0;
int totalRows = table.getRows().size();
```

We'll create a loop that continues as long as `currentRow` is lower than `totalRows`:

```
while (true) {
    // available height of the page
    float available_height = 770;
    // how many rows fit the height?
    while (available_height > 0 && currentRow < totalRows) {
        available_height -= table.getRowHeight(currentRow++);
    }
    // we stop as soon as all the rows are counted
    if (currentRow == totalRows)
        break;
    // we draw part the rows that fit the page and start a new page
    table.writeSelectedRows(currentRowStart, --currentRow, 36, 806, canvas);
    document.newPage();
    currentRowStart = currentRow;
}
```

In this loop, we have already filled two pages: one showing row 1 to 48, another one showing row 49 to 96. When we break out of the loop, the currentRow is 99 and the currentRowStart is 96 (this is the row index for row 97). This means that only row 97, 98 and 99 will be shown. We want to show 5 rows, so we change the value of `currentRow` accordingly.

```
if (currentRow - currentRowStart < 5)
    currentRowStart = currentRow - 5;
table.writeSelectedRows(currentRowStart, currentRow, 36, 806, canvas);
```

Please take a look at the resulting PDF, you'll see that the third page starts with row 95 (a row that was already shown on page 2).

**Update:** I misinterpreted the question in the sense that I thought that rows needed to be repeated only if there's an orphaned handful of rows on the final page. The actual requirement was to *always* repeat 5 rows every time the table is split.

I've slightly updated my original example. See [RepeatLastRows2](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/RepeatLastRows2). You changed the value of `currentRowStart` so that the start goes back 5 rows, but you forgot to update the `currentRow` value. As a result, you don't subtract sufficient space from the available height.

Also make sure you don't introduce endless loops (or `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions`) by repeating the same 5 rows over and over again if only 5 rows (or less) fit a single page.

Comment: From the way you explained your post, I think this is what im looking for (with some minor changes). I'll give you an update to this after I get some sleep.

Comment: i made some alterations to your code. I removed if(currenRow - currentRowStart <5 ) condition and added -5 to currentRowStart=currentRow (became currentRowStart=currentRow). When I ran the code, row 93 and part of row 94 is printed on 2nd page. Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: What went wrong? You broke it ;-) Please download the original sample I posted in itextpdf.com;  adapt it and post the complete sample (e.g. in your question) so that we can reproduce the problem. Just telling us what you changed doesn't help much (it's also not clear why you'd change it that way). Also: which version of iText are you using?

Comment: I actually adapted your code. I'm using version 5.4.4. Here's the code: http://pastebin.com/ZPZ6xzVx. What i actually want (as stated in the main post) is to print the last 5 rows of previous page to every new page. So if we deal with 3 pages (like in your code), 2nd page should also contain the last 5 rows from the 1st page. Hope I relayed this clearly. :)

Comment: Aha, I didn't get your initial requirement. I'll take a look at your updated example.

Comment: Honest mistake there. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the recently introduced `PdfPTableEventAfterSplit` which is triggered when a table needs to be split.  It is triggered after the current page is rendered, but before the next page is started.  You can use it to duplicate the rows you want to repeat on the next page.

```
class RepeatSplitEvent extends PdfPTableEventForwarder {
    @Override
    public void afterSplitTable(PdfPTable table, PdfPRow startRow, int startIdx) {
        for (int i = startIdx - 5; i < startIdx; i++) {
            table.getRows().add(0, table.getRow(i));
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
// ...
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);
table.setTableEvent(new RepeatSplitEvent());
// ...
```